# How do I distribute fillings evenly in flan/pudding mix?

Tags: pudding, flan

I bought the following flan/pudding

[image: Happiness with pieces of chocolate]

I followed the instructions:

- 300 ml of cold milk
- add content of the package
- beat 3 minutes until fluffy

However the small pieces of chocolate were all on the side of the bowl. Is there a way to have them uniformly distributed inside the cream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After they're stuck to the bowl, lightly "fold" them in.

Youtube search for "Folding Ingredients" [here](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=folding+ingredients)...